# Is there a way to determine whether vibration turned on or off in settings?

Tags: ios

I mean information from slider in Settings->Sounds->Vibrate.

Comment: Please expand your question to provide more information, examples, your work etc..  Otherwise it may be closed for low quality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot read system settings. iOS didn't provide such APIs for you to access system preferences.